# Problems with installing package haven

Tags: r, install.packages, r-haven

I'm trying to install the package haven, but when opening it in the library it is said: there is no package "hms". So I've tryed to install the packing "hms". But it gives me this error messages:

```
> install.packages("hms", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Merete/OneDrive - uni-muenster.de/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
         binary source needs_compilation
ellipsis  0.1.0  0.3.0              TRUE
rlang     0.3.4  0.4.6              TRUE
vctrs     0.1.0  0.3.0              TRUE
hms       0.4.2  0.5.3             FALSE

  Binaries will be installed
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/ellipsis_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 30847 bytes (30 KB)
downloaded 30 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/rlang_0.3.4.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 1080437 bytes (1.0 MB)
downloaded 1.0 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.4/vctrs_0.1.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 499748 bytes (488 KB)
downloaded 488 KB

package ‘ellipsis’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot remove prior installation of package ‘rlang’
package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Merete\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpakYjr4\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘hms’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/hms_0.5.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 134669 bytes (131 KB)
downloaded 131 KB

ERROR: dependency 'rlang' is not available for package 'hms'
* removing 'C:/Users/Merete/OneDrive - uni-muenster.de/Dokumente/R/win-library/3.4/hms'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Merete\OneDrive - uni-muenster.de\Dokumente\R\win-library\3.4" C:\Users\Merete\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpakYjr4/downloaded_packages/hms_0.5.3.tar.gz' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘C:\Users\Merete\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpakYjr4\downloaded_packages’
> library(hms)
Error in library(hms) : es gibt kein Paket namens ‘hms’  (there is no package "hms)
>
```

I am new to R, so there might be an easy answer to this, but on my own I was not able to solve the problem.

Comment: you need to first install rlang package as shows in the error and after that install the package

Comment: Can you run `remove.packages("rlang")`? The problem is that some old version of it is blocking the update.